# Difference between flat and apartment

Tags: meaning

Could you please differentiate between `flat` and `apartment`. I am a bit confused about using them.

Answer (score 4):

"Flat" is chiefly British and Commonwealth English.  Traditionally a flat is an apartment that is on one level, with no internal stairs, but this isn't always the case.

"Apartment" is more common in American English. Other than that, the meaning is the same.

You say "Block of flats" but "Apartment block".